# Trying to install letsencrypt on ubuntu 12.04 using certbot-auto program, but getting 404 errors when it does apt-get update

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-installation, ssl, letsencrypt

I'm trying to install letsencrypt on my ubuntu 12.04, but i'm getting these 404 errors that i'm not too sure how to resolve them.

I don't understand why this happens all the time for me. I install something awhile back and it works fine, but overtime these things disappear for some reason. Can someone explain to me why does this happen, when someone releases an app, why don't they just include all the necessary files with the package being installed instead of downloading it on the spot?

```
Bootstrapping dependencies for Debian-based OSes...
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [55.4 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [55.5 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [149 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [502 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [4,643 B]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [56.9 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [3,036 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages [689 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [8,837 B]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [136 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [10.5 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,069 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages [10.9 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages [144 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3,367 B]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [767 kB]
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.4 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages [288 kB]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [10.8 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [152 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3,547 B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [17.1 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [1,149 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.3 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [296 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [17.3 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Fetched 5,629 kB in 7s (727 kB/s)
apt-get update hit problems but continuing anyway...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
gcc is already the newest version.
gcc set to manually installed.
python is already the newest version.
python-dev is already the newest version.
python-dev set to manually installed.
augeas-lenses is already the newest version.
libaugeas0 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2-mpm-prefork apache2.2-common apache2.2-bin
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libssl1.0.2 python-setuptools
Recommended packages:
  python-pip
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libffi-dev libssl1.0.2 python-setuptools python-virtualenv
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ca-certificates libssl-dev openssl
3 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 234 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,312 kB/7,169 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,584 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libssl1.0.2 openssl libssl-dev
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ precise/main libssl1.0.2 amd64 1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ precise/main openssl amd64 1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ precise/main libssl-dev amd64 1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1
  404  Not Found
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a bad ppa repository. This sometimes happens over time. It typically means that the software author is no longer supporting their software (libssl1.0.2, openssl, libssl-dev), and removes the files at their end.

In `terminal`...

```
cd /etc/apt               # change directory
grep ondrej sources.list  # search for ondrej
```

if this grep returns an answer, then...

```
sudo gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list  # edit the file
```

and place a `#` at the front of the offending line. Save the file and quit gedit.

Next we'll search in all *.list files...

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d  # change directory
grep ondrej *.list          # search for a {filename}.list
```

You'll probably only get one filename as the output of the grep command. Note the filename. Next we'll delete that file...

```
sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/enter_filename_here.list
```